# R markdown: nice way to show a long text in a html table

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, knitr, kable

Let's say I want to show this table in a R markdown file:

```
test.df <- data.frame(A = 'test', B = 'wow', C = paste0(1:10000, collapse = ', '))
kable_styling(kable( test.df, caption="test df" ))
```

However this will make the C column enormous which looks ugly when I would export it to a html file, especially if there would be more rows.

[image]

Is there a way to adjust the styling such that the table looks neater, for example:

- Show column `C` in a textbox with a scrollbar that has a defined `width` x `height`
- Make the text in column `C` collapsed and visible when the user clicks on something like "expand"
- Other suggestions are welcome ;)

Comment: I'm curious to see what responses you receive. Would you consider using `DT::datatable` and adding a button to show/hide columns (`ColVis` extension)?

Comment: @Ben Yeah may be a good option as well

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the most straightforward solution is to use CSS.

The `kableExtra::cell_spec()` function can be used to embed the cell content in a `span` element. Displaying this span as a block and setting width and height should be sufficient to add scrollbars.

Here is a reproducible example:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
test.df <- data.frame(A = 'test', B = 'wow', C = paste0(1:10000, collapse = ', '))
test.df$C <- kableExtra::cell_spec(
  test.df$C, 
  extra_css = "display: block; overflow: scroll; height: 5em; width: 20em;"
)

kableExtra::kable_styling(knitr::kable(test.df, caption="test df", escape = FALSE))
```
````